# How to get the value, who first returned one of the threads

Tags: ruby, multithreading

I'm need handle who first return not `nil` value from one of the threads and kill other threads.
For example i have this code:

```
require 'benchmark'
a = nil
puts "I'm need 1 second for test..."
result_time = Benchmark.measure {
    while true
      t1 = Thread.new { a = nil unless a } unless t1
      t2 = Thread.new { a = 1 unless a; sleep 1 } unless t2
      t3 = Thread.new { a = 1 unless a; sleep 2 } unless t3
      t1.join
      t2.join
      t3.join
      if !a.nil?
        t1.kill if t1
        t2.kill if t2
        t3.kill if t3
        break
      end
    end
}.real

if result_time >= 2.0
  puts "Bad. More than 1 second. result_time: #{result_time}"
else
  puts "Cool. Less than 2 seconds."
end
```

This code returned:

```
I'm need 1 second for test...
Bad. More than 1 second. result_time: 2.00074989994755
```

So i want 1 second for this test (not 2). Please help and sorry for my english:)

Comment: Is this only a learning experiment, or are you planning to use this in an important project? If it's the latter, you'll need to be concerned about race conditions, synchronization, and the fact that threads may not run their code in the same order that you create them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just delete `t1.join, t2.join and t3.join`...Becouse method `.join` stop main thread. But don't know why result time >= 1 and <=2. I think sleep instuction not been executed, becouse main thread just kill second when `a = 1` in `while` loop without waiting sleep insturuction.
Final code:

```
require 'benchmark'
a = nil
puts "I'm need 1 second for test"
result_time = Benchmark.measure {
    while true
      t1 = Thread.new { a = nil unless a } unless t1
      t2 = Thread.new { a = 1 unless a; sleep 1 } unless t2
      t3 = Thread.new { a = 2 unless a; sleep 2 } unless t3
      if !a.nil?
        t1.kill if t1
        t2.kill if t2
        t3.kill if t3
        break
      end
    end
}.real
```

if result_time >= 2.0
  puts "Bad. More than 1 second. result_time: #{result_time}. a: #{a}"
else
  puts "Cool. Less than 2 seconds. result_time: #{result_time}. a: #{a}"
end

Returned me:

```
I'm need 1 second for test
Cool. Less than 2 seconds. result_time: 0.001799600024241954. a: 1
```